# How to open a Excel file using a command button in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a button so that when pressed it opens a excel document.
the name of the excel file is Solution.xls and it is placed in the desktop

Comment: You want MS Excel to load with the file Solutions.xls, right?

Comment: What sort of C# application is this? ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your button click event handler:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Solution.xls")
Process.Start(filePath);
```

If Excel is already open, it will open the file in the current instance; if not, a new instance of Excel will be created. This also assumes that the target PC associates .xls files with Excel, but that is a fairly safe assumption if Excel is installed.

Comment: what if need to check if excel is present or not and if not then open it in notepad

Comment: Opening an .xls in Notepad not highly recommended; it is a binary file format. Nonetheless, if Excel is not installed, you can associate .xls files with whatever application you desire through Windows.